# Vimeo OAuth Error - he consumer key passed was not valid

Tags: python-2.7, vimeo-api

Am trying to get authenticated with the API and it is saying **"The consumer key passed was not valid." msg="Invalid consumer key"**. Before that it was saying that the oauth_signature is invalid and I have struggled for a day with it and now that error is not showing up. Please find my code in the above gist.

You help is much appreciated on this.

Comment: The gist you included has secure keys. In response, the app you linked has been disabled, and you will need to create a new app. I'll reply with a more detailed answer in a second, just wanted to update you here first.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of reasons that you might see this error, all of which mean that your oauth 1.0a protocol is likely incorrect.

I highly recommend you test your app alongside this tool : http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/authentication/

Below are the important steps to check.

1. Compare your base string to the Hueniverse base string. If they match, you are likely signing incorrectly. If they do not match make sure you are sorting the parameter keys properly
2. If the base string matches, check your signature method and your signing process. The secret of your request should be client_secret& OR client_secret&token_secret. Note the ampersand always exists.